# Apply jitter uniformly across geoms in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**I would like to jitter two geoms by the same amount**. Consider the following minimal example:

```
library(ggplot2)
pdat <- data.frame(x = c(1,1,2,2,4,4,8,8),
                   y = c(1,1.1,2,2.2,3,3.3,4,4.4),
                   ymin = c(1,1.1,2,2.2,3,3.3,4,4.4)-.9^(0:7),           
                   ymax = c(1,1.1,2,2.2,3,3.3,4,4.4)+.9^(0:7),
                   colour = as.factor(rep(1:2,4)))

ggplot(pdat, aes(x=x,y=y,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,color=colour)) + 
    geom_linerange(position='jitter') + geom_point(position='jitter')

ggplot(pdat, aes(x=jitter(x),y=y,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,color=colour)) + 
    geom_linerange() + geom_point()
```

which produces the following plots:
[image: ggplots]

In both cases, the jittering is random across geoms (the points and lineranges are in different locations), whereas I would like them to be consistent for each data point (the points in the middles of the corresponding lineranges). Is this possible?

Note that **I would not consider manually adding noise to the `x` variable to be a solution** as this would destroy the ability to apply coordinate transformations. E.g., defining `pdat$x2 <- pdat$x+rnorm(8)/10`,

```
ggplot(pdat, aes(x=x2,y=y,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,color=colour)) + 
    geom_linerange() + geom_point()
```

looks good, but then the variance of the jitter is subject to any subsequent transformations as can be seen in

```
ggplot(pdat,aes(x=x2,y=y,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,color=colour)) + 
    geom_linerange() + geom_point() + scale_x_log10()
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `position_jitter` function, you can add a `seed` value to get reproducible jitter effect:

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(pdat, aes(x = x, y = y, ymin = ymin, ymax = ymax, color = colour))+
  geom_point(position = position_jitter(seed = 123, width =0.2))+
  geom_linerange(position = position_jitter(seed = 123, width = 0.2))
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I wanted. It is still mysterious to me why `ggplot(pdat, aes(x=jitter(x),y=y,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax,color=colour)) +  geom_linerange() + geom_point()` doesn't work though. Is `jitter` called separately by each geom?

Comment: Glad that it works. Yes, I guess that you're right and that each geom is applying a jitter effect on its own. I think you can also ad jitter effect outside of `ggplot2` by doing `pdat$x <- jitter(pdat$x)`.

Comment: yes, but you can make it use the same jitter yb setting the seed with this monster : `ggplot(pdat, aes(x={set.seed(123); jitter(x)},y=y ...`

Comment: @user20650, Interesting call of jitter ;) I didn't know this kind of writing :D thanks for sharing this.