# Space between two dots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, geom-point

The spaces between two dots are vary, some are very far, and some are very narrow. And also, the order between two dots is likely random (Some are "non-transplan" are in the left, some are in the right). Meanwhile, my desire plot is the spaces between two dots and also the order of the group are same for all the data.

How do I fix this?

I use ggplot and geom_jitter:

```
ggplot(Play1, aes(x=Month, y=Species, size=Value, color=Status)) +
  geom_jitter(width=0.1, height = 0)
```

I also tried with position_nudge & position_dodgebut I cannot use geom_point because geom_point make the dots are on top of each other.

```
jitter(position = position_dodge(width=0.5))
```

[My plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jItg8.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO! It would be easier to help you if you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data bets shared using `dput()` or some fake data or some built-in dataset.

Comment: This approach might work for you to make the jittered points be as close as possible to their ideal location: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67929830/6851825

Comment: This might also be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60981619/apply-jitter-uniformly-across-geoms-in-ggplot2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there seems to be only one observation by `Month`, `Species` and `Status` one option would be to use `geom_point` with `position_dodge()` and to explicitly map `Status` on the `group` aes so that points get dodged by `Status`. This will put one status group on the left and the other on the right.

Using some fake random example data:

```r
set.seed(123)

Play1 <- expand.grid(
  Month = month.name[9:12],
  Species = LETTERS,
  Status = c("Nontransplan", "Transplan")
)
Play1$Value <- runif(nrow(Play1), 0, 250)

library(ggplot2)

ggplot(Play1, aes(
  x = Month, y = Species,
  size = Value, color = Status
)) +
  geom_point(
    aes(group = Status),
    position = position_dodge(width = .5)
  ) +
  # Just for the reprex
  scale_size_area(limits = c(0, 250), max_size = 3)
```

[image]